# format number angular in component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**hello,**

I have a number that I am trying to transform into my ts file but I can't get it to work.

here is the number: 123456.059

expected result: 1.234

Thanks for your help.

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

class MyService {
  constructor(private _decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

  transformDecimal(num) {
    return this._decimalPipe.transform(num, '1.2-2');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Answer: `return this._decimalPipe.transform(num, '1.0-3');`

### '1.0-3' Explanation:

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
```

- minIntegerDigits: The minimum number of integer digits before the decimal point. Default is 1.
- minFractionDigits: The minimum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 0.
- maxFractionDigits: The maximum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 3.

So, one number is an entire, and it can have maximum 3 decimals. I.e: 5.456449 => 5.456

Source: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#usage-notes

Comment: If you want ```123456.059``` to be ```1.234``` with this, then you'll have to parse the number to string, remove the dot, parse to number again, and then, edit your code with my correction.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom pipe and use it . Check the following link. I have already created for you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-pipe-cn4mv4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

app.component.html

```
<p>{{ 123456.059 | tonumber }}</p>
```

number.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'tonumber',
})
export class NumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return (value / 100000).toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?/)[0];
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NumberPipe } from './usernames.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, NumberPipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Evidence**

[image]